# dragging-issue carousel-item with dropdown in Firefox

Tags: html, angular, hammer.js, ngu-carousel

i have an issue within my Angular7 application using the NguCarousel (uses HammerJS).

The carousel works as intended for displaying complex elements, until I add a html-select element in the carousel items.

**Problem**: 
When clicking the select the whole carousel becomes draggable in Firefox.

This can be seen when editing [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngu-carousel-demo) a bit.
In simple.component.html replace in row 3 `{{item}}` with `<select></select>`

**Already tried the following things:**

- change framework: I have seen the same behaviour in swiper-framework (therefore probably not really framework related)
- stop the event propagation with `<select (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">` but that didn't help.
- css touch-action: none one select

What else can i try?

Best regards

Terry

Edit: Still having this issue. A hint/idea would be splendid!

Comment: interesssting...looks like the carousel is interpreting it as a drag event.
Possible workaround use a custom select component:
https://netbasal.com/create-a-custom-select-component-in-angular-complete-with-virtual-scrolling-c29e24f72006
and replace it with the <select></select>

Comment: the thing is, i kinda need it as select element since it should be rendered by the os (e.g. mobile phone select overlay). otherwise i would have used bootstrap dropdown by now. If nothing works i will switch to a non-select way, but would prefer if i can adjust something to make it work with the standard select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HammerJS uses [pointerdown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/pointerdown_event) event to catch the start of dragging process.

So, that's probable what you wanted to stop from being propagated.

```
<select (pointerdown)="$event.stopPropagation()">
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngu-carousel-demo-rdfqzy?file=src/app/simple/simple.component.html)**